# create unique project code in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have two forms one is client with fields clientname and clientcode and another  is project with fields clientname dropdown and projectname.

I want to create unique projectcode in a specific pattern i.e clientname=sports and clientcode=spr.

I tried creating a function called ProjectID where I have stored day, month, year in a variable prID and fetching clientcode using join query and stored in another variable cltcode and then concatenating these two variables to a third one projectcode and returning this projectcode.

I got this error "Not all code paths return a value"

and when I uncomment the return projectcode; statement after finally block it says "use of unassigned local variable projectcode"

here is my code please help

```
public string ProjectID()
    {
        string prID = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        long ID = Convert.ToInt64(prID);
        string projectcode;
        string cltcode;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cltcode = cmd.CommandText = "SELECT com.compcode from company_code AS com JOIN client_code AS cl ON com.compname = cl.clientname";
            string clientcode = cltcode.ToString();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            projectcode = clientcode + ID;
            return projectcode;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string message = "create id error";
            message += e.Message;
        }
        //return projectcode;
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        return projectcode;

    }
```

Comment: use of unassigned local variable projectcode just means that you have not assigned a value to projectcode, which is true, because you have declared it without an initial value. Also you should be aware that by returning projectcode within the try block, the connection will never be closed. consider returning the project code only at the end of the method, and choose a default, or re-raise the exception after closing the connection

Comment: This code is ugly you know. What is the reason in so many variables using? Have you heard about String.Format?

Comment: @anatol thank you for feedback I will try to make it good

Comment: @Nirmala very well that you have took this positively

Comment: @anatol can you help me resolve the join query issue? actually its not returning value from database, the whole select statement is assigned to the cltcode variable. when I execute this query in DB it runs successfully.

Comment: @Nirmala *when I execute this query in DB it runs successfully* - how many rows it returns?

Comment: my client_code table have 8 rows and its returning exactly 8 rows.

Comment: @Nirmala *its returning exactly 8 rows* - so how you imagine placing this result into string variable? Your result isn't string, it's set. You need to transform it into plain text in query or work with set on client side

Comment: @anatol can you provide me solution for this or any reference please I am new to .net

Comment: @Nirmala have you googled? *sqlcommand c#* try with this search query

Answer (score -1):

**"Not all code paths return a value"?**

You need to have a return to this:

```
catch (Exception e)
 {
     string message = "create id error";
     message += e.Message;
     return message;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

try these things:

First initialize your variable as `string projectcode = null;`
Second remove this line `return projectcode;` from the try scope.

Comment: Thank you@yonan2236 error resolved but I did not got value from this query "SELECT com.compcode from company_code AS com JOIN client_code AS cl ON com.compname = cl.clientname"; the whole query is assigned to the variable

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that if your `try{}` block fails, then `projectcode` does not get assigned.

In your declaration use:

```
string projectcode = "";
```